# Bash regex to strip quotes from array element

Tags: regex, arrays, bash

I'm trying to find a way to remove double quotes from all of the elements of an array that I have in a script that I'm writing. All of the examples that I have found so far are either for doing this to an entire file using grep, awk, sed, or not in bash.

This is the block of code that I have so far:

```
vol_filter=( $(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filter "name=attachment.instance-id, values=instance-id" | jq '[.Volumes[] | {VolumeId}]') )
vol_id_array=( )
regex=[[:alpha:]][-][[:xdigit:]]
for i in ${vol_filter[@]}
do
  if [[ $i =~ $regex ]]
  then
    vol_id_array+=( $i )
    echo ${vol_id_array[@]}
  fi
done
```

The output that I get from running the script as it is now is

"foo-bar" "herp-derp"

and what I want is

foo-bar herp-derp

Comment: Any particular reason you wouldn't want to use sed?

Comment: When I first looked at the documentation for sed it looked like I could only use it for files. Looking at it more closely I see now that I could have used sed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change that assignment to

```
vol_id_array+=( "${i//\"}" )
```

This [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) will cause $i to be expanded without any quotes in it as it's added to the array.